# Does anyone know how to change all colours to another of a pdf?

Tags: python, pdf, colors, rgb

I'm having a PDF of 3 different colours including white, black and red. But I want to convert its red colour to another with Python(it can be any other software also)

In short, I need a Python program(or software) that has the capability to change any specific color of a particular PDF to another given color.

Comment: Many things can be colored in a PDF, so at a minimum you'll need to be more specific about what you want to do.

Comment: Can you provide an example PDF, and clearly indicate exactly which "red colour" you want to change (screenshot).